# Find a Git branch containing changes to a given file

Tags: git

I have 57 local branches. I know I made a change to a certain file in one of them, but I'm not sure which one. Is there some kind of command I can run to find which branches contain changes to a certain file?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Find all branches which contain a change to FILENAME (even if before the (non-recorded) branch point)

```
FILENAME="<filename>"
git log --all --format=%H $FILENAME | while read f; do git branch --contains $f; done | sort -u
```

Manually inspect:

```
gitk --all --date-order -- $FILENAME
```

Find all changes to FILENAME not merged to master:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads | grep -v master | while read br; do git cherry master $br | while read x h; do if [ "`git log -n 1 --format=%H $h -- $FILENAME`" = "$h" ]; then echo $br; fi; done; done | sort -u
```

Comment: Do I need to replace anything in this command besides FILENAME? It returns all 57 branch names.

Comment: @Dustin: If all 57 branches contain that filename, then all 57 branches contain a change which includes that filename.  Branches start from the oldest revision reachable on that branch, even if that revision existed before you created the branch (the branch is in some senses retroactively created).  I think you need to define your problem better.  Do you know what the change is?  Could you use `git log -Schange …` or `git log --grep LOGMESSAGE …` (with … representing the rest of the command I mentioned).

Comment: @Dustin: Another option is to use `gitk --all -- filename` which will graphically show you all of the changes to that file.  If you can identify the commit in question, then you can use `git branch --contains` to see what branches the commit has migrated to.  If you want to see what branch the commit in question was *originally* created on, then google git-what-branch, but be aware that fast-forward merges can obscure that information.

Comment: @Seth: I couldn't remember the commit message or exact code change. I just have a general idea. The problem is that it is not merged with master yet, so in order to use gitk I would still have to checkout each branch to find what I'm looking for.

It would be nice if I could say, "git, show me the branches that made changes to FILENAME since its branch point"

Comment: @Dustin: `gitk --all [--date-order] -- filename` does NOT make you check out each branch.  It will show you all changes on all branches.

Comment: @Dustin: See edit for git-cherry solution.  Your clue that the change was not merged to master may help you.

Comment: You could write the first line more efficiently `git log --all --format='--contains %H' "$file" | xargs git branch`

Comment: @Geo: gitk is sometimes an extra package. Try `apt-get install gitk` or `dnf install gitk` or the appropriate similar command for whatever OS you are running.  gitk was actually the reason I first switched to git, though I quickly found tons of other good reasons.

Comment: Tip: you need to know at least one branch **on which the file exists**, checkout it and only then run the "git log" (I struggled for some time with "fatal: ambiguous argument ...file... unknown revision or path not in the working tree." and resolved it with this simple step)

Comment: @AndrzejMartyna: I believe the second and third variants I posted do not require that, they search everywhere.

Answer (score 80):

All you need is

```
git log --all -- path/to/file/filename
```

If you want to know the branch right away you can also use:

```
git log --all --format=%S -- path/to/file/filename | xargs -I{} -n 1 echo {} found in && git branch --contains {}
```

Further, if you had any renames, you may want to include `--follow` for the Git log command.

Comment: That will show the commits, but he asked which branch.  Add a `--source` on there and you're golden.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that shows all branches for each commit. But it would help.

Comment: True, but in this particular case he was only looking for one.

Comment: btw for asp.net path should be in format like AppName/Controllers/XController.cs

Answer (score 21):

Looks like this is still a problem without an appropriate solution. I don't have enough credits to comment, so here's my little contribution.

Seth Robertson's 1st solution kinda worked for me, but only gave me local branches, among which where many false positives, probably because of merges from the stable branch.

Adam Dymitruk's 2nd solution didn't work for me at all. For starters, what's --format=%5? It isn't recognized by git, I couldn't find anything about it and I couldn't get it to work with other format options.

But his 1st solution combined with the --source option and with a simple grep proved helpful:

```
git log --all --source -- <filename> | grep -o "refs/.*" | sort -u
```

This gives me a number of remote tags and branches and one local branch, where I made the latest changes to the file. Not sure how complete this is.

**UPDATE** as per @nealmcb 's request, sorting branches by most recent change:

First, you could change the grep to "refs/heads/.*", which will give you the local branches only. If there are only a few branches, you could examine the latest commit of each one like this:

```
git log -1 <branch> -- <filename>
```

If there are more branches and you really want to automate this, you can combine the two commands using xargs, git log formatting and another sort into this one-liner:

```
git log --all --source -- <filename> | grep -o "refs/heads/.*" | sort -u | xargs -I '{}' git log -1 --format=%aI%x20%S '{}' -- <filename> | sort -r
```

This will result in output like this:

```
2020-05-07T15:10:59+02:00 refs/heads/branch1
2020-05-05T16:11:52+02:00 refs/heads/branch3
2020-03-27T11:45:48+00:00 refs/heads/branch2
```

Comment: Great - thank you. Now how about sorting by most recent change?

Comment: The utility of that last long command is _**OMGWTFBBQ**_ level AMAZING. Absolutely beautiful. Don't let the votes on the other answers from an eight-year head start fool you. That's gold, Jerry! (except this time it really is)

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is ancient, but I kept coming back to it before developing my own solution. I feel it's more elegant and thanks to use of merge base filters out unwanted branches.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
base=${2:-master}

b=$(tput bold) # Pretty print
n=$(tput sgr0)

echo "Searching for branches with changes to $file related to the $base branch"

# We look through all the local branches using plumbing
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/); do
  # We're establishing a shared ancestor between base and branch, to only find forward changes.  
  merge_base=$(git merge-base $base $branch)
  # Check if there are any changes in a given path.
  changes=$(git diff $merge_base..$branch --stat -- $file)

  if [[ ! -z $changes ]]; then
    echo "Branch: ${b}$branch${n} | Merge Base: $merge_base"
    # Show change statistics pretty formatted
    git diff $merge_base..$branch --stat -- $file
  fi
done
```

If you put it in PATH as `git-find-changes` (with executable permissions) - you can then call it with `git find-changes /path`

Example output for
`git find-changes app/models/`

```
Branch: update_callbacks | Merge base: db07d23b5d9600d88ba0864aca8fe79aad14e55b
 app/models/api/callback_config.rb | 28 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 28 insertions(+)
Branch: repackaging | Merge base: 76578b9b7ee373fbe541a9e39cf93cf5ff150c73
 app/models/order.rb                 | 38 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 38 insertions(+)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this - it really helped me out today. 
One small amendment - the usage should be git-find-changes <target> once you've added it to your path. You missed the hyphen between git and find.

Comment: Glad it worked for you @Phil but there's no error :) `git` has this handy feature that it will allow you to issue any command in format `git command-name` as long as `git-command-name` executable is in $PATH. it will also display help (if provided) with `git help command-name` this example does not provide that  help but that's why I shown it like that in the example

Comment: Needs a run through Shellcheck (e.g. we need to quote `$file` in case some idiot has whitespace in filenames).  And we can easily `[ "$changes" ]` instead of `[[ ! -z $changes ]]` to make this a portable (faster) shell script.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an inelegant brute-force method, but I expect it should work. Make sure you've stashed any uncommitted changes first as it will switch which branch you are currently on.

```
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads); do
    git checkout $branch && git grep SOMETHING
done
```

Comment: Because if you know the change you can use `git log -S`

Comment: What shell are you assuming? Bash?

Comment: No bashisms, that should work on POSIX. I'm not sure that `for-each-ref` still respects that `short` flag though. That said, ignore my answer; the other answers are better.