# How to find out the pull requests which include a change in a particular file?

Tags: git, github

Work on a big open source repository in Github. There are more than 300 pull requests (PR) waiting the queue to be merged to master branch.

I'd like to add features in a file, before to do that, I need to make sure there are no exist PRs making the same change.

So how to find out the pull requests which include a change in a particular file?

Comment: Try Github API: [list-pull-requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) and  [list-pull-requests-files](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files), you could filter all the PRs including changes in the particular file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get help from @Philippe and @knight9631, I got the expect result.

#### Prerequisite

Do `upstream` change as described in @Philippe's reply.

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/[orga]/[project].git

# add fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/* to .git/config in session origin

$ git fetch --all
```

#### Get the related PRs which are still not merged.

Run below script.

```
FILENAME=$1

git log --all --format=%d $FILENAME|awk -F "[\/|\)]" '/pr/{print $3}' |sort -n |while read line
do
  state=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/pulls/$line|jq -r .state)
  if [[ $state == "open" ]]; then
    echo "PR $line hasn't been merged"
  fi
done
```

#### Demo

```
$ bash PR.sh abc.json

PR 22857 hasn't been merged
PR 19231 hasn't been merged
PR 22981 hasn't been merged
```

#### Notes:

You need to add authorization token when getting Github API. Otherwise you will easily hit the [rate-limiting](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting)

```
TOKEN="<your_own_token"

state=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/pulls/$line|jq -r .state)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to fetch all the PR branches in your local repository and then search for commits modifying the files.

Do achieve that, do:

1. Add the project repository as the `upstream` remote.

   `git remote add upstream https://github.com/[orga]/[project].git`
2. Open the `.git\config` file and add the line `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/upstream/pr/*` to the `[upstream]` section. It should ends up looking like this:

   `[remote "origin"]
       fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
       url = https://github.com/[orga]/[project].git
       fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`
3. Do a `git fetch --all` that will fetch all the remotes
4. Search for updates on the files you want:

[List all commits (across all branches) for a given file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466709/list-all-commits-across-all-branches-for-a-given-file)

or even better for your need...

[Find a Git branch containing changes to a given file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258440/find-a-git-branch-containing-changes-to-a-given-file)

Comment: Thanks, @Philippe. I follow the steps, but didn't get the expect result. Only show master branch. Where should I put step 2 in? `upstream` or `origin`?

Comment: Got it, I use this command `git log --all --format=%d $FILENAME|grep pr` to get all related PR numbers, but can't identify which one are still opened (not merged or closed).

Comment: I get it worked with your help. The next question is, after I get the PR numbers, how to show the changes from each open PRs in that file?